# Android copy file to /system/bin/sh, now devices can not booted

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, reboot

to day I add one daemon file to android devices, I use command:

```
 ./adb push XXXXX   /system/bin/sh
```

I say done, but when i restart the device, now it can not boot, no logo appear, just black screen, although I see the light is enabling. I can not know what can I do now, how can i fix it... plz

Comment: Instructions vary on phone brand/model, but you'll need to reflash stock firmware, which may or may not erase all your data. If you end up flashing the exact same build number, your data may still be there.

Comment: @AaronGillion Would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: hello. My device is a board, then only connect to this by using "adb". The problem is now the device can not booted, and I can not coonect to device to, can not connect to recovery mode.
 Sorry if I have a silly question, but can you explain more how can i solve it

Answer (score 1):

USE FASTBOOT INSTEAD...Shell/sh has been replaced by

```
adb push  xxxx  /system/bin/sh
```

Shell controls the adb commands, So ADB is now disabled ! ...    What you need to do is reboot into FASTBOOT using the device specific button code while the phone starts
(usually home and volume up together for 10 seconds) or(power and volume up )
Once inside FASTBOOT you need to replace your boot.img and system.imgSystem then boot

```
fastboot flash system xxxx.img

fastboot flash boot xxxx.img
```

XXXX represents the .img file name

Comment: Hi, can i enable fastboot through other action, because my board does not have volume, home, back... botton, only screen... :(

Comment: What board are you using ?

Comment: the old board made by my partner, use your own SDK android, and does not have home, press, volume button... and used android 4.0 only

Comment: Fastboot can only be accessed with adb reboot-bootloader or button combination... Replacing SH shouldn't of caused a boot error however... You should still see a boot logo and a boot loop after that !...

Comment: hi, are your sure for "  Replacing SH shouldn't of caused a boot error however" , as I saw, the boot logo not shown, even I saw a light ( black screen ) in screen appear. I think the problem is the software. not by hardware.

Comment: When making the board, did you include a pre-boot recovery.. Some devices include a recovery accessible by removing the battery fully and plugging back in ... Then it loads the device in devices on pc... You need a driver .. I think it's called something like V-COM Driver

Comment: yeah, i think i have to contact to my partner to solve it,  thanks you very much for teach and explain me about this problem. Hmmm, I think i will back to ask you some thing more, sir :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you pushed xxx to replace your Shell Binary in bin... 
Shell is not a folder but a binary file... 
If you have replaced this on purpose with a custom binary, then you needed to run a

```
adb chmod 0755 /system/bin/sh
or
adb shell  chmod 0755 /system/bin/sh
```

Adb Shell Might work because you have replaced the shell in system, You can run a remote shell command..
If you can still connect in any way..

> IM NOT SURE ABOUT THE EXACT PERMISSION, 0775, 0755, 0777

Comment: hello, I think the problem is I can not use "ADB SHELL" command, because the device not boot , just black screen.  So I can not connect to devices through " adb connect X.X.X.X"

Comment: Hi, if I wrong, please teach me, i am new about using linux command :)

Comment: Forget ADB and try using Fastboot ... Use Fastboot by holding the opposite button of Recovery... For example, if Volume Up is recovery, use Volume Down at boot , + the usual extra buttons - home or power ...

Comment: P.s   > ADB connect is not a command...( ADB DEVICES) - (ADB REBOOT )-(     ADB WAIT-FOR-DEVICE )-(ADB PUSH/PULL)........